# Grails problem with nullable contraint in domain class

Tags: grails

I'm having the following problem with grails' 1.2.1 domain classes:

When I set a constraint attr(nullable:true) and attr is **int** or **bool**, this condition isn't reflected in the db (postgresql 8.4). However, if attr is a **String**, the DB is consistent with the situation.

Any hints ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use Integer and Boolean if you're using the nullable constraint.